# Can I prevent Windows 7 from restoring my brightess setting when the power state changes?

Tags: windows-7, laptop, battery, power-management

I have a question regarding Windows 7.

I have set different values for the screen brightness when on battery and when on AC power (in the power plan settings). If I manually change the brightness of the screen (using the brightness +/- buttons on my keyboard), the brightness value is also modified in the power plan, and it is restored the next time the laptop is in the same power state as it was when the modification occurred.

Is there a way to make the manual setting of the screen brightness temporary, i.e. not affect the power plan settings?